# я пытаюсь посчитать градусную меру угла трегольника , но выводит: -nan(ind), что делать?

Tags: c++

corner1 = acos((pow(b, 2) + pow(c, 2) - pow(a, 2)) / 2 * c * b);

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаменатель оберни в скобочки. А то арккосинус от какой-то фигни, которая вне области определения берется.